Nim lang LSP Extension for VSCode Broken?
I haven't touched Nim for 2 years now and I wanted to get back into it, but while setting up the LSP server for Nim, I ran into a problem. It seems like Nimsuggest crashes without a reason. I tried downloading nimlangserver from nimble but it didn't solve anything. I also tried to ask in the Nim discord server but no luck. I tried uninstalling Nim and reinstalling, constantly restarting both VSCode and the LSP extension, but nothing changes. Here's my LSP info tab:

Does anyone else encounter this issue? Any help is appreciated.
